# Why can't I store a small integer in a uint8_t type?

Tags: c++, types

If I store the number 2 in a uint8_t type and try to print it I get nothing. Surely an 8 bit integer can store the number 2. What am I missing?

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    std::uint8_t x = 2;
    std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
x =
```

Comment: Is this program behaving as you say, this exact program?

Comment: I was missing #include <iostream> which I've added above. Aside from that ,yes.

Answer (score 8):

`uint8_t` will usually be a typedef for `unsigned char`, and will be printed as a character.

`2` is some unprintable character value though, so you don't get any meaningful output.

You can use `+x` to promote x to an integer, and it will be printed as such.

Comment: Can confirm with gcc and clang: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97165e443ff64103)